# Como usar jQuery para adicionar dinamicamente campo de texto no formulário

Tags: jquery, html, aplicação-web

Estou com um formulario onde o cliente precisa informar o numero de portas do patch panel, e de acordo com o valor que ele preencher este campo, aparecer mais novos campos dinamicamente para adicionar outras informaçoes relevantes.

Exemplo: to cadastrando um novo patch e informo que ele tem 5 portas no formulario, assim que preencher, em seguida eh pra exibir 5 novos campos de entrada para ele informar o que cada porta ira conectar. Ja tentei alguns codigos porem sem sucesso.

Meu form HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Número de portas:</label> <input type="text"
                name="patchpanel.numPortas" class="form-control"
                value="${flash['patchpanel.numPortas'] ? flash['patchpanel.numPortas'] : p?.numPortas}">
            <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'patchpanel.numPortas' /}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="inputs">
            <label for="quantidade">Equipamento conectado:</label> <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="adicionarcampo"><img src="/public/images/plus.png"></a><br>
            <input type="text" name="portas.descricao[]" placeholder="Informe o equipamento contectado a porta" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
```

minha jQuery:

```
var max_fields = 10;
var wrapper = $(".inputs");
var add_button = $("#adicionarcampo");

var x = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
$(add_button).click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var length = wrapper.find("input:text.textAdded").length;

if (x < max_fields) {
x++;
$(wrapper).append('<div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remover</a><input type="text" name="portas.descricao['+ (length+1) +']"class="form-control" placeholder="Informe o equipamento contectado a porta" /></div>');
 }

 });


 $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).parent('div').remove();
 x--;
 });

 $("#alert-target").click(function () {
toastr["success"]("I was launched via jQuery!")
});

})
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde ele tras portas como NULL
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Falta fechar uma `div` antes desse `</form>`

Comment: O que exatamente você precisa?

Comment: os novos campos preenchidos precisam ser salvos no banco juntamente como os outros. Desse jeito como ta, ele nao ta salvando no banco. Tipo em numero de portas eu salvo no banco passando o **name="patchpanel.numPortas"** e pra salvar a descricao das portas era pra ser ***name="portas.descricao"** mas por algum momento nao ta pegando os valores do campo

Comment: @CarlosDiego como você quer que seja os dados inseridos?

Comment: strings que possam pegar a descriçao dos equipamentos, coloquei numeral mas na vdd serao nomes.Na vdd todos os campos estao sendo como Strings.

Comment: Entendeu @EGDEV? voce pode me ajudar nessa pergunta tbm: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218979/como-posso-gerar-url-tempor%C3%A1ria-para-recuperar-senha-no-framework-play/219290#219290

Comment: Desculpa a demora para responder, pois estava sem tempo. Pelo que entendi você não está conseguindo pegar os dados dos novos campos adicionados?

Comment: Em relação a sua outra pergunta crie uma página de redefinição de senha, essa página ira receber um parâmetro na url que pode ser informação como data e hora da solicitação de troca de senha e o id ou e-mail do usuário, essa informação seria codificada por exemplo em base64, a pagina buscaria com esse código no banco de dados qual o usuário para fazer a troca de senha, esse código deve ter um tempo de expiração, se o usuário não acessar a página exemplo em 3 horas terá que pedir novamente o link para recuperação de senha, para isso so gravar no banco a data e hora da

Comment: solicitação depois e só verificar o tempo de diferença entre a data gravada no banco de dados e a data recebida pelo parâmetro da url, se o tempo de diferença entre as duas datas/hora for maior que 3 horas não ira permitir a troca de senha e o usuário terá que pedir novamente a recuperação de senha.

Comment: @EGDEV consegui resolver o problema de pegas os valores dos campos e salvar no banco. Obgdo pela ajuda

Comment: @EGDEV olha outro problema que estou tendo baseado na sua ajuda ja. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220166/guardar-valores-temporariamente-em-campos-de-texto-inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar assim:

```js
var max_fields = 10;
var wrapper = $(".inputs");
var add_button = $("#adicionarcampo");

var x = 1;
$(add_button).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var length = wrapper.find("input:text.textAdded").length;

  if (x < max_fields) {
    x++;
    $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="campo' + (length+1) + '"class="form-control" placeholder="Seu texto" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remover</a></div>');
  }

});


$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
  x--;
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Informando Quantidade -->
<form id="formQuantidade"> 
  <label for="quantidade">Informe a quantidade</label>
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" name="campo[]"  class="form-control" placeholder="Seu texto">
    <br>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="adicionarcampo" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Adicionar Campo</a>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Implementei como vc fez porem o meu campo de texto nao aparece. vou atualizar a pergunta com sua implementação

Comment: me tira outra duvida, eu quero validar os novos campos no meu banco assim como fiz em outros forms <div class="form-group"> <label>Número de portas:</label> <input type="text" name="patchpanel.numPortas" class="form-control" value="${flash['patchpanel.numPortas'] ? flash['patchpanel.numPortas'] : p?.numPortas}"> <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'patchpanel.numPortas' /}</span> </div> como fazer com esse novos campos dianicamente?

Comment: vou atualizar a pergunta ja com sua implementaçao e minha nova duvida.

Comment: @CarlosDiego tenta atualizaz sua pergunta com sua implementação.

Comment: Pronto @EGDEV, atualizado

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar usar o exemplo abaixo, acredito que seja o que você precisa

```js
const $formDinamico = $("#formDinamico");
$formDinamico.hide();

$("#formQuantidade").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //limpa form dinamico antes criar novos inputs
  $formDinamico.empty();
  //pega quantidade
  let quantidade = $("#quantidade").val();
  //retornando a quantidade informada de inputs
  let inputsDinamico = criaInputs(quantidade);
  
  $formDinamico.append(inputsDinamico);
  $formDinamico.append(criaBotaoSubmit());
  $formDinamico.show();
  
})

//pegando valores do form dinamico
$formDinamico.on('submit',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).serialize());
});

function criaInputs(quant){
  let html = '';
  for(let i = 1; i <= quant; i++){
    html += '<input type="number" class="form-control"    class="inputDinamico" name="valor'+i+'" placeholder="Inputs Dinamico">';
  }
  return html;
}

function criaBotaoSubmit(){
  let html = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Enviar</button>'
  return html;
}
```

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css);

.btn{
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.inputDinamico{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Informando Quantidade -->
  <form id="formQuantidade"> 
     <label for="quantidade">Informe a quantidade</label>
    <input id="quantidade" type="number" class="form-control"    name="quantidade">
    <button id="enviarQnt" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Enviar</button>
  </form>
  
  <!-- via jquery "imprime" a quantiade de inputs necessários -->
  <form id="formDinamico">
  
  </form>

</div>
```

No seu caso invés de fazer um for e imprimir a quantidade que form passado no parâmetro você pode simplesmente direto já retornar o input

Comment: Deu certo cara, obgdo. Tinha esquecido de referenciar o arquivo JS