# Como posso gerar URL temporária para recuperar senha no framework play?

Tags: aplicação-web, play-framework, password

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicaçao web usando o framework play 1.4(versao didatica) e quero implementar a funcionalidade de recuperaçao de senha onde o usuario ira colocar seu email e será enviado um link temporario para o mesmo redefinir sua senha. Minha duvida, como gerar esse link temporario enviar para p email preenchido e validar a nova senha?

Meu MODEL funcionario onde ja add public String token;
    Date tokenValidityDate; que sei que serão necessarios: `package models;

```
 import javax.crypto.Cipher;
 import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
 import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.EnumType;
 import javax.persistence.Enumerated;

 import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
 import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

 import play.data.validation.MinSize;
 import play.data.validation.Required;
 import play.db.jpa.Model;
 import sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar.Date;

 @Entity
 public class Funcionario extends Model {

final static String chave = "0123456789abcdef";
private static final String ALGORITMO = "AES";
private static byte[] mensagemEncriptada;
private static byte[] mensagemDescriptada;
private static SecretKey key;

public String nome;

public String funcao;

public String nivelAcesso;

public String login;
@MinSize(4)
public String senha;

public String email;

public String token;
Date tokenValidityDate;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status status;

public Funcionario() {
    status = Status.ATIVO;
}

public boolean autenticar() throws Exception {
    Funcionario u = Funcionario.find("login = ? and senha = ?", login, descriptografar(senha)).first();

    if (u == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


public static String descriptografar(String mensagem) throws Exception {

    key = new SecretKeySpec(chave.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    mensagemDescriptada = cipher.doFinal(mensagem.getBytes());

    return StringUtils.trim(Base64.encodeBase64String(mensagemDescriptada));
}
}
```

`
Minha pagina html de recuperar senha:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@{'/public/stylesheets/login.css'}">
 <title>Octopus</title>
 </head>
 <body background="/public/images/back.png">
 <form action="@{Logins.logar}" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="login.id" value="${u?.id}" />
 <div class="login">
 <p><center><small>Digite seu endereço de e-mail para redefinir a senha.</small></center></p></small>
<input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="funcionario.email" value="${flash['funcionario.email'] ? flash['funcionario.email'] : u?.email}"  > 
<span class="bg-danger">#{error 'login.email' /}</span>  
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
 </div>
 <div class="shadow"></div>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: O que eu faria no meu nível atual e foi o que veio na cabeça: Ao solicitar a troca de senha, seria passado o e-mail, esse e-mail servira para buscar qual usuário esta registrado e enviar o link quando gerado. Descoberto qual usuário, alguém geraria um token que ira representar esse usuário e servira como parâmetro para uma url valida. O solicitante receberia no e-mail o link(url+token), ao acessar seria verificado se esse token é valido, caso sim, busca o usuário que é representado pelo token, efetua a troca de senha e invalida o token, para que essa ação não possa ser mais acessada.

Comment: exatamente isso, mas na pratica nao tenho ideia de como implementar, vc tem algum exemplo parecido que possa me ajudar?

Comment: Vou tirar um momento para escrever uma resposta debulhando essa "teoria" para te ajudar a ter uma luz nesse túnel.

Comment: opa, fico agradecido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Ao solicitar a troca de senha, seria passado o e-mail, esse e-mail
>   servira para buscar qual usuário esta registrado**

Alguém ira chamar sua entidade responsável pelo acesso ao banco e buscar qual usuário esta registrado com esse e-mail. Digo alguém, pois depende como você implementou ou vai implementar sua arquitetura, mas em resumo, alguem tem que ir buscar esse usuário no banco.

> **Descoberto qual usuário, alguém geraria um token que ira representar
>   esse usuário e servira como parâmetro para uma url valida.**

Com o usuário identificado, no caso retornado o registro do banco, devera ser gerado um token. Esse token seria constituído por um tempo de vida(expiração), para que possa ser temporário. Quando ele expirar, é deletado/invalidado, logo sendo desvinculado do usuário e não pode ser mais usado.

Para ele "representar" o usurário, eles devem estar ligados de alguma forma que o sistema encontre/entenda. Por exemplo, ter um campo ou tabela que crie um relacionamento entre o token e o seu usuário. Com essa ideia, depois de gerar o token você registraria/vincularia esse token ao usuário.

> **e enviar o link quando gerado.**

Por fim você já tem o link pronto, com o mesmo e-mail enviado como solicitação, você enviara ao usuário para troca de senha.

> **O solicitante receberia no e-mail o link(url+token), ao acessar seria
>   verificado se esse token é valido, caso sim, busca o usuário que é
>   representado pelo token, efetua a troca de senha e invalida o token,
>   para que essa ação não possa ser mais acessada.**

Como o objetivo é uma url e que seja temporária, você criaria uma action que recebera esse token como parâmetro, ao receber esse parâmetro é verificado se esse token é valido(ele expirou ?, existe? etc), caso ainda seja valido, você buscaria no banco qual usuário esta vinculado a esse token, sabendo realmente quem quer efetuar a troca de senha.

retorna a view, o usuário troca a senha com sucesso(caminho de update normal) e então você invalida o token para que ele não possa ser utilizado novamente, se o usuário quiser trocar a senha novamente, ira ter que fazer todo processo anterior.

Na correria, mas é isso.

Obs: Deve ter alguma biblioteca que faça a geração de tokens, faça uma pesquisa.

Comment: voce tem algum exemplo pronto que possa me mostrar como base, pois estou com dificuldades de implementar sua logica.