# tabela dataTable nao funciona corretamente

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-datatables

Estou implementando uma dataTable no meu projeto web, ja refiz a implementaçao da dataTable varias vezes pra sanar o problema, porem sem exito. O problema é que as caracteristicas do dataTable nao funcionam na minha tabela. Como podem ver abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ja adicionei os arquivos da dataTable no repositorio do meu projeto, baixei diretamente do DataTables.net. 
meu arquivo html esta assim:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#tabela1').DataTable();
});
</script>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <a     href="@{Application.index}">Dashboard</a></li>
<li class="active"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Funcionários</li>
</ol>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
        onclick="window.location.href='/funcionarios/formFuncionarios';">
        Novo funcionário</button>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <input type="hidden" name="funcionario.id" value="${f?.id}" />
    <table id="tabela1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-over">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Função</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>#{list items:funcionarios, as:'f'}
            <tr>
                <td>${f.nome}</td>
                <td>${f.funcao}
                <div class="pull-right action-buttons">
                    <a href="@{funcionarios.editarFuncionarios(f.id)}" class="edit"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> Editar</span></a> <a
                        href="@{funcionarios.removerFuncionarios(f.id)}" class="trash"
                        data-toggle="confirmation" data-btn-ok-label="Sim"
                        data-btn-ok-class="btn-success" data-btn-cancel-label="Não"
                        data-btn-cancel-class="btn-danger"
                        data-title="Remover funcionário"
                        data-content="Tem certeza que deseja excluir este registro?"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Remover</span></a> <a
                        href="@{funcionarios.detalhesFuncionarios(f.id)}" class="flag"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"> Detalhes</span></a>
                </div></td>

            </tr>#{/list}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

lembrando que no meu main.html ja esta referenciando os scripts usados:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="@{'public/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'}"/>
<script src="@{'public/javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'}"></script>
<script src="@{'public/js/custom.js'}"></script>
<script src="@{'public/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'}"></script>
<script src="@{'public/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js'}"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="@{'public/js/bootstrap.min.js'}"></script>
```

Ao inspecionar a pagina vejo este erro, so que nao localizo o erro nesse trecho de codigo.

Comment: Abra o console do seu navegador e vê se retorna algum erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Faz essa alteração no seu código:**

Troca essa linha `$('#tabela1').dataTable();` por essa `$('#tabela1').DataTable();`

**OBS:** Seu .DataTable(); esta assim dataTable(); em minúsculo a primeira.

**Código correto:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabela1').DataTable();
});
```

A função **DataTable** foi definida como MAIÚSCULA em https://datatables.net/ se você chamar a função em minúscula `.dataTable();` eu creio que não funcionará.

@Edit

**Código funcional:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
<table id="myTable" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="index.php">alguma coisa</a></td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**OBS:** não sei sobre JS ainda, mas.. é esse o erro que encontrei.

Comment: eu já tinha colocado DataTable antes e tbm não funcionou. :(

Comment: @CarlosDiego coloquei um código funcional pra você comparar com o seu, e ver se tem algo de errado. Fiz alguns testes, e esta funcionando como `dataTable();` também, bom.. o jeito é você ir tentando até que alguém que tenha conhecimento de JS venha aqui ^^.

Comment: Funcionou Nicolas, obgdo